# Software that allows to create and practice Multiple Choice Questions tests for personal use

Tags: windows, android, linux, web-apps

I am basically looking for a [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) like test application for personal use, where I can create Question + Multiple Choice Answer Time Limited digital tests so I can prepare myself for similar tests by somewhat simulating testing conditions. I don't want to use Moodle because it involves setting up a personal server and other such things which is too much for basic personal use. I have contemplated using Flashcard applications like Anki or Quizlet to make cards that have a question on the front and the related answer on the back but this would not properly simulate how real tests are taken. I dual boot Windows and Linux Mint on my laptop so the application could be on either of these platforms or both. Android app is not necessary but it would be useful. Open source or Freeware applications preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a csv file with one question and 2 or more possible answers for each question, with the first one always being the correct answer.

A couple of minutes python scripting will give you a console app that will load the csv file, select N random lines, randomise the answers for that question and assign them to options from A onward, and then present each answer in turn with the options and prompt the user for answer letters. Marking would be simple.

A little more work with pygame or curses could give a reasonably nice interface or a GUI such as wxPython could be added or possibly a web interface.

All of the above is Open Source - *I know that it is not a ready rolled application but this was much too long for a comment*.

Comment: I've barely learnt the basics of python as of now so I don't think I'm good enough yet for making GUI applications. But this could be a interesting side project to work on for a while.